# "Save for later" for articles and publishing pages, where does it save?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, spfx

I'm planning to make a custom web part that using the users articles/pages that they have "saved for later". However, I have no clue to WHERE to get this information, or where its stored.

The "save for later" can be found on the social bar.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Save for later" Favorites are added and read via an undocumented API and thus not recommended for production.

If you go to F12 Dev tools you might discover calls similar to these:

`https://TENANT_REGION-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/documents/saveForLater?start=0&count=20`

You can get the URL of the endpoint for your region and the token by calling `/_api/sphomeservice/context?$expand=Token` from a SharePoint page.

[image]

After you have a token, endpoint URL and and your absolute site URL, you need to add two headers to all your GET calls:

```
headers: {
'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
'sphome-apicontext': `{"PortalUrl":"${this.props.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl}"}`
}
```

Send your GET request to `https://REGION-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/documents/saveForLater?start=0&count=20`

**Update**

Adding "Save for later": requres a GET call to `/api/v1/documents/saveForLater/add`with these URL params: siteId, webId, listId, uniqueId

> https://REGION-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/documents/saveForLater/**add**?**siteId**=765d4b61-1bc6-42b7-9667-94c343fbf859&**webId**=93e10f19-d8b4-491e-90d8-c3e766fbe497&**listId**=0ba06207-75ff-4aa9-87c7-f859dec39bcc&**uniqueId**=70e6835b-5ee0-4581-bb73-0c2ed3c43044

Removing "Save for later": requres a GET call to `/api/v1/documents/saveForLater/remove` with these URL params: siteId, webId, listId, uniqueId
Removing "Save For later": (siteId, webId, listId, uniqueId)

> https://REGION-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/documents/saveForLater/**remove**?**siteId**=765d4b61-1bc6-42b7-9667-94c343fbf859&**webId**=93e10f19-d8b4-491e-90d8-c3e766fbe497&**listId**=0ba06207-75ff-4aa9-87c7-f859dec39bcc&**uniqueId**=70e6835b-5ee0-4581-bb73-0c2ed3c43044

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if its possible to do a POST? Like a custom "bookmark" button that puts a article to the "save for later" page?

Comment: Updated the answer. I think, there is only GET calls for adding/removing "save for later" items.